# VTK: plot line segments

Tags: c++, plot, vtk

I need to plot line segments (not continous) combined in one chart.
In order to create a plot I use the code from the VTK [example](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Plotting/LinePlot) but when I skip some values when filling `vtkTable` line goes down to zero value. And if creating another plot and skip some of the first elements the line goes up from zero. So I need to solve these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution myself. It appears very simple at last. The basic idea is to represent each line segment by its own plot and to use a separate table for each of the plots. One more improtant point all of the tables do not need to have the same step on the X-axis.
Here is the sample code:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkContextView> view = vtkSmartPointer<vtkContextView>::New();
view->GetRenderer()->SetBackground(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkChartXY> chart = vtkSmartPointer<vtkChartXY>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkTable> table1 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTable>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray> xAxis1 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray>::New();
xAxis1->SetName("X");
vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray> yAxis1 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray>::New();
yAxis1->SetName("");
table1->AddColumn(xAxis1);
table1->AddColumn(yAxis1);
table1->SetNumberOfRows(2);
table1->SetValue(0, 0, 1);
table1->SetValue(0, 1, 1);
table1->SetValue(1, 0, 2);
table1->SetValue(1, 1, 2);

vtkPlot* plot1 = chart->AddPlot(vtkChart::LINE);
plot1->SetInputData(table1, 0, 1);
plot1->SetColor(0, 0, 255, 255);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkTable> table2 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTable>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray> xAxis2 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray>::New();
xAxis2->SetName("X");
vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray> yAxis2 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray>::New();
yAxis2->SetName("");
table2->AddColumn(xAxis2);
table2->AddColumn(yAxis2);
table2->SetNumberOfRows(3);
table2->SetValue(0, 0, 4);
table2->SetValue(0, 1, 4);
table2->SetValue(1, 0, 5);
table2->SetValue(1, 1, 5);
table2->SetValue(2, 0, 6);
table2->SetValue(2, 1, 6);

vtkPlot* plot2 = chart->AddPlot(vtkChart::LINE);
plot2->SetInputData(table2, 0, 1);
plot2->SetColor(255, 0, 0, 255);


view->GetScene()->AddItem(chart);
view->GetInteractor()->Initialize();
view->GetInteractor()->Start();
```

P.S. You can also specify several rows with the same x coordinate.